# Asset_sync gem skipping PDF files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline

I recently configured the asset_sync gem to sync all of my assets to Amazon S3.  I deploy on Heroku, and for whatever reason, it seems to be skipping all PDF files in my `/app/assets` directory.  I haven't told it to exclude any files, why might this happen?

I've followed this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31, and as such I don't have an `asset_sync.rb` initializer file.

I've tried moving the PDFs to their own dir, `/app/assets/pdfs`, and no dice there either.

Strangely, I have a .zip file in the `/app/assets/images` dir, so it seems like specifically PDFs are being skipped.

Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 2.0, Heroku Cedar Stack, current release of `asset_sync` gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had added `*.pdf` to my `.slugignore` file, and Heroku was tossing out the PDF files on deploy.  DERP!